# How to filter and group pandas DataFrame to get count for combination of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am sorry I could not fit the whole problem in the Title in a concise way. Pardon my English. I will explain my problem with an example.

Say I have this dataset:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["2020-11-13", 0, 3,4], ["2020-10-11", 1, 3,4], ["2020-11-13", 2, 1,4],
                             ["2020-11-14", 0, 3,4], ["2020-11-13", 1, 5,4], 
                             ["2020-11-14", 2, 2,4],["2020-11-12", 1, 1,4],["2020-11-14", 1, 2,4],["2020-11-15", 2, 5,4],
                             ["2020-11-11", 0, 1,2],["2020-11-15", 1, 1,2],
                             ["2020-11-18", 1, 2,4],["2020-11-17", 0, 1,2],["2020-11-20", 0, 3,4]]), columns=['Timestamp', 'ID', 'Name', "slot"])
```

I want to have a count for each `Name` and `slot` combination but disregard multiple timeseries value for same ID. For example, if I simply group by `Name` and `slot` I get:

```
dff.groupby(['Name', "slot"]).Timestamp.count().reset_index(name="count")


  Name slot count
    1   2   3
    1   4   2
    2   4   3
    3   4   4
    5   4   2
```

However, for `ID == 0`, there are two combinations for `name == 1` and `slot == 2`, so instead of `3` I want the count to be `2`.

This is the table I would ideally want.

```
  Name slot count
    1   2   2
    1   4   2
    2   4   2
    3   4   2
    5   4   2
```

I tried:

```
filter_one = dff.groupby(['ID']).Timestamp.transform(min)
dff1 = dff.loc[dff.Timestamp == filter_one]
dff1.groupby(['Name', "slot"]).Timestamp.count().reset_index(name="count")
```

But this gives me:

```
  Name slot count
    1   2   1
    1   4   1
    3   4   1
```

It also does not work if I drop duplicates for `ID`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
x = dff.groupby(["Name", "slot"]).ID.nunique().reset_index(name="count")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  Name slot  count
0    1    2      2
1    1    4      2
2    2    4      2
3    3    4      2
4    5    4      2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have accepted an answer. I have one more question, hopefully you know how to solve it. Say instead of looking for unique value in `ID`, I need to look for the unique combination of two columns. Assume I don't have column `ID` but I have two other columns `A` and `B` instead. How do I do something like `dff.groupby(["Name", "slot"])['A,'B'].nunique().reset_index(name="count")`

Comment: @BlueMango I'd use `.drop_duplicates()`, but this qualifies for new question. Open a new question here on SO and I'd try to look at it