# How to get unique count of two columns based on unique combination of other two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up question for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471330/how-to-filter-and-group-pandas-dataframe-to-get-count-for-combination-of-two-col/67471460)

Say I have this dataset:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["2020-11-13",3,4, 0,0], ["2020-10-11", 3,4,0,1], ["2020-11-13", 1,4,1,1],
                         ["2020-11-14", 3,4,0,0], ["2020-11-13", 5,4,0,1], 
                         ["2020-11-14", 2,4,1,1],["2020-11-12", 1,4,0,1],["2020-11-14", 2,4,0,1],["2020-11-15", 5,4,1,1],
                         ["2020-11-11", 1,2,0,0],["2020-11-15", 1,2,0,1],
                         ["2020-11-18", 2,4,0,1],["2020-11-17", 1,2,0,0],["2020-11-20", 3,4,0,0]]), columns=['Timestamp', 'Name', "slot", "A", "B"])
```

I want to have a count for each `Name` and `slot` combination but disregard multiple timeseries value for same combination of `A` and `B`. For example, if I simply group by `Name` and `slot` I get:

```
dff.groupby(['Name', "slot"]).Timestamp.count().reset_index(name="count")


  Name slot count
    1   2   3
    1   4   2
    2   4   3
    3   4   4
    5   4   2
```

However, for `A == 0 && B == 0`, there are two combinations for `name == 1` and `slot == 2`, so instead of `3` I want the count to be `2`.

This is the table I would ideally want.

```
  Name slot count
    1   2   2
    1   4   2
    2   4   2
    3   4   2
    5   4   2
```

I tried:

```
filter_one = dff.groupby(['A','B']).Timestamp.transform(min)
dff1 = dff.loc[dff.Timestamp == filter_one]
dff1.groupby(['Name', "slot"]).Timestamp.count().reset_index(name="count")
```

But this gives me:

```
  Name slot count
    1   2   1
    1   4   1
    3   4   1
```

It also does not work if I drop duplicates for `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you may just need to drop the duplicates based on the combination of the grouper columns with  A and B before grouping:

```
u = dff.drop_duplicates(['Name','slot','A','B'])
u.groupby(['Name', "slot"]).Timestamp.count().reset_index(name="count")
```

---

```
  Name slot  count
0    1    2      2
1    1    4      2
2    2    4      2
3    3    4      2
4    5    4      2
```